Seeking Guidance on Revising a Retraction Decision to a Correction with COPE's Assistance
I recently faced a challenging situation regarding a paper that was retracted for not meeting the quality standards initially expected. However, after reviewing the concerns, I believe that the issues in the paper could have been appropriately addressed through a correction rather than a full retraction.
I'm considering reaching out to the Committee on Publication Ethics (COPE) for support in revising the decision, but I'm unsure of the best approach. Has anyone here worked with COPE in similar circumstances? Would they be able to assist in this kind of situation where a correction might be more suitable than a retraction?
Any experiences, suggestions, or advice on how to proceed with COPE would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!

What does "not meeting the quality standards initially expected" mean? I've seen plenty of authors who have made ridiculous claims about their papers deserving correction when they should be obviously retracted, so I admit to being quite skeptical when I hear of another...

Is this about Protzko et al.?

How big of a correction would have been needed? Would the main findings have to be corrected? Both aspects are important factors according to the COPE Guidelines for deciding on a retraction over a correction. And, presumably, there is some room for the journal to make a judgement call.

One would think editors would be really in to figuring out the quality of a submitted ms before accepting it.

@Anyon Main finding is same, the data in raw file is in agreement with the published ones however unintended a graphical presentation issue happens , i provided the raw data to confirm the data integrity and the corrected graph to avoid this appearance misleading. Journal said unable to verify the data integrity from raw provide file. I make then a video show that data was taken directly from the raw file not misleading to verify the data integrity however the journals ignore all materials
